# Convert 8Mono pixel data array into 24bit image in c#

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, type-conversion

I am using mvfox-igc camera sdk for getting images from that camera my problem is that i have byte array of mono8 image and i want to convert that pixel data into 24bit image my programming language
can anybody help me please my code looks like this but is is not doing its work properly

```
            processedBitmap = new Bitmap(data.request.imageWidth.read(),data.request.imageHeight.read(),PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            unsafe
            {
                BitmapData bitmapData = processedBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, processedBitmap.Width, processedBitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, processedBitmap.PixelFormat);

                int bytesPerPixel = System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(processedBitmap.PixelFormat) / 8;
                int heightInPixels = bitmapData.Height;
                int widthInBytes = bitmapData.Width * bytesPerPixel;
                byte* PtrFirstPixel = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;
                byte* firstby = (byte*)data.request.imageData.read();
                int indexx=0;
                Parallel.For(0, heightInPixels, y =>
                {
                    byte* currentLine = PtrFirstPixel + (y * bitmapData.Stride);
                    for (int x = 0; x < widthInBytes; x = x + bytesPerPixel)
                    {
                        currentLine[x] = firstby[indexx];//((byte*)data.request.imageData.read())[0];//(byte)oldBlue;
                        currentLine[x + 1] = firstby[indexx];//((byte*)data.request.imageData.read())[0];//(byte)oldGreen;
                        currentLine[x + 2] = firstby[indexx];//((byte*)data.request.imageData.read())[0];//(byte)oldRed;
                        indexx = indexx + 1;
                    }
                });
                processedBitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
                processedBitmap.Save("bmp.jpg");
```

Comment: `indexx + 3`???

Comment: @aybe No, that's the 8-bit pointer. It's 1 byte per pixel, not 3.

Comment: @OP: you change the `currentLine` pointer in every Y line, but don't have an equivalent pointer for the 8-bit data, and instead use `firstby` directly all the time. This means you're replacing all lines in your 24-bit image with just the data of the first line of the 8-bit data.

Comment: @Nyerguds Ah yes, you're right!